# OS X Visual Effect View in Interface Builder not display correctly

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode6, interface-builder, nsvisualeffectview

I am trying to edit a Visual Effect View in an OS X project in Interface Builder, but all the Visual Effect View and its contents disappear/reappear randomly. When I change Core Animation layers, sometimes they seem to appear correct again, but when I move anything, it disappears again.

I am on Xcode 6.4 and OS X 10.10, with deployment target latest OS X, but this problem was apparent before too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a behind-window vibrant background not being repainted when I moved the window. The problems went away when I ensured that all ancestor views up to the content view had layers.

Comment: I had another problem that was fixed when I forced the top view (the superview of the content view) to have a layer.